# How to check if item doesn't exists then and only update the div quantity

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/673h38g9/14/

When clicked on the plus icon , and minus icon , i am calculating and adding it to the myOrderPanel_footer div .

I dont want to increase the quantity if the plus icon is clicked on the same Item

How can i check if the item doesn't exists then only i want to increase the quantity

sample logic when clicked on the plus icon

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function (e) {
        var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
        $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(value+1);
        var currentsellprice =  parseFloat($(this).parent().prev().data('sellprice')); // get the data "price" of item
        var currentquantity =parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
        $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.Itm_right_aside .sellprice').text(currentsellprice*currentquantity);
        if(currentquantity>=1)
        {
        addquantitytoMyordersfooter();
        var subtotalvalue = parseInt($(".myOrderPanel_footer .subtotal").data('subtotal'));
        subtotalvalue = subtotalvalue + currentsellprice ;
        $(".myOrderPanel_footer .subtotal").data('subtotal',subtotalvalue);
        $(".myOrderPanel_footer .subtotal").text(subtotalvalue)
        }
         displaylogicforfooter();
});
```

I need your suggestion should i maintain a global array or is there any other feasable solution to approach this ??

Comment: which item does not exist, which html elemet are you talking about?

Comment: what do you mean by same time?

Comment: Each item has a class by name TreeMenu_Content with a unique id .

Comment: For example here there are 2 items Item1 with id as itemcontent703
and Kool with id as  itemcontent693.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/673h38g9/15/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny , yes like that , but sorry to mention that the basic functionlaity is not working know (Increasing of price)

Comment: so you want the price to keep increasing in each click but the order count to remain same

Comment: yes correct exactly .